# С++ Почему инициализация std::array выглядит именно так?

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>

struct Student
{
    std::string m_str;
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Student, 3> arr{
        {
            {"str0", 100},
            {"str1", 101},
            {"str2", 102}
        }
    };

    std::cout << arr[0].m_str << " " << arr[0].m_value << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[1].m_str << " " << arr[1].m_value << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[2].m_str << " " << arr[2].m_value << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Пожалуйста, об'ясните, почему при инициализации arr ми используем две пары фигурных скобок (по-идее, первая пара - это uniform инициализация, а вторая?)

Если убрать одну пару, то
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Из-за особенностей [агрегатной инициализации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Хотите без лишних сrобок - укажите тип явно: `std::array<Student, 3> arr = { Student{"str0", 100}, Student{"str1", 101}, Student{"str2", 102}};`

Answer (score 4):

У вас на самом деле стоят аж три пары скобочек (то бишь аж три инициализатора для первого поля), хотя в такой ситуации достаточно будет только одной в которой будет заключено 2 (по одному инициализатору для каждого поля) х 3 (по количеству объектов) = 6 инициализаторов:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct Student
{
    std::string m_str;
    int m_value;
};

std::array<Student, 3> arr
{
    "str0", 100
,   "str1", 101
,   "str2", 102
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/necovG

Comment: Я бы запятые [так](https://godbolt.org/z/1bas19) ставил, кстати. Так они соответствуют количеству строк и сохраняется плюс добавления нового элемента без редактирования предыдущей строки в диффе

Answer (score 4):

У `std::array` нет конструкторов (кроме сгенерированных компилятором автоматически), поэтому он инициализируется списком полей в фигурных скобках. Это называется [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

У него одно поле - обычный массив. Что-то в духе вот этого:

```
namespace std
{
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct array
    {
        T elems[N];
        // ...
    };
}
```

Поэтому одна пара скобок - для всего `std::array`, а вторая для этого внутреннего массива.

В некоторых случаях одну пару скобок можно опускать, но не здесь (точные условия см. по ссылке выше).