# Инициализация std::array в C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в C++20 (не знаю, как в других версиях) не работает следующий код?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>

    struct Car
    {
        std::string make{};
        std::string model{};
    };

    int main()
    {
        // error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<Car, 3>’
        std::array<Car, 3> cars = {{"1", "11"}, {"2", "22"}, {"3", "33"}};

        return 0;
    }
```

Вместо этого я должен использовать uniform-инициализацию:

```
    std::array<Car, 3> cars {{{"1", "11"}, {"2", "22"}, {"3", "33"}}};
```

Хотя если брать массив не структур, и фундаментального типа, то всё работает:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>

    int main()
    {
        // объявление std::array<int, 2> nums {{3, 4}}; тоже работает
        std::array<int, 2> nums = {3, 4};

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: copy-initialization не стоит использовать, даже если код еще компилируется.

Comment: А так не пробовали? :) `std::array<Car, 3> cars = {Car{"1", "11"}, Car{"2", "22"}, Car{"3", "33"}};`

Comment: [С++ Почему инициализация std::array выглядит именно так?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1174899), [Инициализация массива std::array структурами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257211).

Comment: На самом деле у `std::array` очень странная инициализация, т.к. это — структура, содержащая массив, а конструктора, принимающего данный массив, нет. Т.к. `std::array`, по определению, есть агрегат, то нужно применять агрегирующую инициализацию через двойные фигурные скобки. Подробнее об этом указано в ссылках выше + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists/8192275#8192275